# If I'm trying to add more than 2 data it is showing exceptin

Tags: java

My program is to add some data into `HashSet` but it is showing concurrentexception this is the code

```
package com.jspiders.arrays;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Smain {

/**
 * @param args
 */
static HashSet hs1;
public static void addstudent(int id,String name,double marks) 
{
    Iterator ite=hs1.iterator(); 
    System.out.println(ite.hasNext());

    if(hs1.size()==0)
    {
     hs1.add(new Student(id, name, marks));
     System.out.println("data entered");
     return;
    }
    while(ite.hasNext())
    {

    Student st1=(Student)ite.next();
    if(st1.id==id)
    {
        System.out.println("duplicte");
    }
    else
    {
        hs1.add(new Student(id, name,marks));
    }



}
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    hs1=new HashSet();

    addstudent(1, "naca", 40);
    addstudent(2, "cjlnca", 20);
    addstudent(3, "sdv", 20);
    addstudent(4, "sdv", 20);


    }
}
```

Comment: That is because while iterating you are increasing the size of hashset.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644568/getting-concurrentexception-when-traversing-a-list

Comment: You don't need to check for duplicate when using `HashSet`. It will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify any collection while iterating. And you adding entry again and again via code

```
{
    hs1.add(new Student(id, name,marks));
}
```

**For duplicate**

HashSet, by defination, stores unique values.

Rough logic of hash set  :

Before adding, hashset invoke `equals` method of about to be added Student with other added Student to check anything is same, if same it will not add otherwise not add.

You dont need to do anything special, just override `equals`  in Student.

```
public booleqn equals(Object obj) {
 Student other = (Student ) obj;
 return this.id.equals (other.id);
}
```

**note you may need to override hashcode too**

Comment: so how can i add to hashset

Comment: When overriding `equals`, you have to override `hashCode` as well. Especially when the objects are to be used in any hash-based container.